# Trying to check if two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement this function that checks if two strings are permutations of each other. The code itself is straightforward.

```
def permutation(a, b)
  if a.length != b.length
    return False
  end
  a  = a.chars.sort.join
  b =  b.chars.sort.join
  return a == b
end

a = "abcedff"
b = "acbedf"
puts (permutation(a, b).to_s)
```

However, when I try to run this file on the terminal, I keep getting an error that says

> permutation.rb:3:in `permutation': uninitialized constant False (NameError)
>       from permutation.rb:13:in`'

I don't understand the reason for this.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is not Python. You want `true` and `false`, not `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over-complicate it. All you need to do is compare two character arrays. For example:

```
def permutation a, b
    a.chars.sort == b.chars.sort
end
```

Given your corpus as posted, this yields:

```
a = "abcedff"
b = "acbedf"

permutation a, b
#=> false

permutation a, a
#=> true
```